# get filenames from a directory without full path

Tags: c#

Is there any function to get filenames without path?

I use

```cs
Directory.GetFiles(directory)
```

And then i replace `directory` with `string.Empty` for each filename, but a GetFilenamesWithoutFullPath would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) which returns file name and extension from full path

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
```

Or even

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Select(Path.GetFileName);
```

Comment: nice, i wasn't using Linq and didn't saw the extension methods in intellisense :-P ... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Use lazyberezovsky's solution or use the FileInfo class that provides a "Name" property.

Comment: Not mine downvote, I think `FileInfo` is also option, but it will create lot of unnecessary information in FileInfo object

Comment: True, but as we don't know what he is going to do with the files, FileInfo may or may not be appropriate.